# Solving renormalization group equations when calculating $\bar{MS}$ mass

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

My textbook gives the RG equation:
$$
\frac{d \bar{m}(\mu)}{d \ln \mu}=\gamma_{m} \bar{m}(\mu) ; \quad \gamma_{m}=-\frac{3 \alpha}{2 \pi}
$$
And then says this is easy to solve and the solution is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\bar{m}(\mu) &=\bar{m}\left(\mu_{0}\right) \exp \left[\int_{\ln \mu_{0}}^{\ln \mu} d \ln \mu^{\prime} \gamma_{m}\right] \\
&=\bar{m}\left(\mu_{0}\right) \exp \left[\gamma_{m} \ln \frac{\mu}{\mu_{0}}\right]=\bar{m}\left(\mu_{0}\right)\left(\frac{\mu}{\mu_{0}}\right)^{\gamma_{m}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Though I can't see how they make this jump to solve the equation, and there seems to be quite little about solving RG equations online. Please could someone break down how they have got to this solution?

EDIT: so I have got as far as:
$$
\bar{m}(\mu) = \gamma_{m} \int \bar{m}(\mu) d\ln{\mu}
$$
I am not sure how they got the form in the first line given from where I am currently.

Comment: Which theory? Which textbook? Which page?

Comment: You tried integrating $d\ln f=\gamma dt$ for $t=\ln \mu$ already? Show your work.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I have edited the question to show where I am currently.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Integrating the expression you gave: $ ln{f} = \gamma \int dt = \gamma t$? I could then impose limits $\ln{\mu_{0}}$ to $ \ln{\mu} $ on t, is this correct? This would give $ \gamma \ln{\frac{\mu}{\mu_{0}}} $?

Comment: So $ f = \frac{\mu}{\mu_0} \exp{\gamma} $, but I am not trying to integrate $d\ln{f}$, I am trying to integrate $d\bar{m}(\mu)$, so how does this solution relate to my problem, and why isn't $\bar{m}(\mu_0)$ involved in the integral - it is a function of $\mu$ yet it just becomes $\bar{m}(\mu_0)$, and lastly, why does $\frac{\mu}{\mu_0}$ go to the power of $\gamma_{m}$, when it was $\exp{\gamma}$? Thanks for the help - I will update my question to be more precise in light of our discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are integrating the *trivial* ODE $\frac{d\ln \bar m(\mu)}{d\ln \mu}= \gamma$, a constant.

So the solution is just
$$
\ln  \frac{ \bar m(\mu)}{ \bar m(\mu_0)}=  \gamma \ln \frac{\mu}{\mu_0}   , \leadsto  \\
    \frac{ \bar m(\mu)}{ \bar m(\mu_0)}= \left (\frac{\mu}{\mu_0} \right )^ \gamma  ,
$$
upon exponentiation.

Comment: Why is it that $ \frac{d \bar{m}(\mu)}{d \ln \mu}=\gamma_{m} \bar{m}(\mu) \rightarrow \frac{d\ln{\bar{m}(\mu)}}{d\ln{\mu}} = \gamma $ ?

Comment: Calculus identity ${dy\over dx} =\gamma y\leftrightarrow {d\ln y \over dx} =\gamma$.